# Configuring and pairing 2 HC-06 Bluetooth modules as Master and Slave using Arduino UNO

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno, master-slave

I have been trying to establish connection between two HC-06 Bluetooth modules. Pairing has been done. The two modules are communicating. My aim is to send a letter from one module and receive acknowledgment from the other module. The code for the master module is below.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial BTserial(2,3); // RX, TX

char c;
char s[]="Matched";
int t[]="NotMatched";

void setup() 
{
    // start the serial communication with the computer
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Arduino with HC-06 is ready");
     // start communication with the HC-06 using 38400
    BTserial.begin(38400);  
    Serial.println("Bluetooth serial started at 38400");
}

void loop()
{  
   // Read from HC-06 and send to Arduino Serial Monitor
   if (BTserial.available())
    { 
        c=(BTserial.read()); 
    if (c=='a')
      {
      Serial.write(s);
      }
    else 
      {
      Serial.write(t);  
      }
    }

    // Read from Arduino Serial Monitor and send to HC-06
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        c =  Serial.read();
        Serial.write(c);   
        BTserial.write(c); 
    }
}
```

Similar code is used for the slave module. Except for the 'else' part in the code everything runs right. I receive acknowledgement along with the else portion being printed twice for both the if and else portion of the code i.e 'matched not matched not matched' is printed when it receives char 'a' and 'not matched not matched not matched' is printed when it receives anything other than 'a' . Can you please give me suggestions on what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you printed the characters that you are reading?

I had a similar problem and I found that the Bluetooth was receiving garbage characters. The reason was because the standard baudrate, of HC-06 modules, is 9600, so if you change:

```
BTserial.begin(38400);
```

to

```
BTserial.begin(9600);
```

In both master and slave, it might work.